# How do use map function over array of objects in React

Tags: reactjs

Having done the necessary to read the data using fetchAPI, I am having problems displaying the content because of the nature of the array.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Home() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

  async function getData() {
    let response = await fetch("https://api.xxxxxxxx.io/something/students");
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }

  //call getData function
  getData().then((data) => console.log(data)); //
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
      .then((data) => {
        setUserData(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(userData).map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>{item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

When I checked the console, the data are displayed but it is only showing **students** with no other data displayed.
I have the data below.

[image]

Comment: Well, `Object.keys(userData)` will give you back `["students"]`. If you want to display all student objects then do `userData.students.map(student => ...)` and access the student properties you want to show.

Comment: Why not just remove the dependency array from `useEffect`? for the Promise resolution? A `useEffect` without a dependency runs every rerender anyway. Also, you can `userData.students.map(({email}) => <p>{email}</p>)`
Edit: Remove the dependency array because, you are calling the `getData` function outside `useEffect` also right.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with React: it's a question about normal JS. But on a React note: stop generating divs in divs. Even though you're using JSX, the _result_ is still going to be HTML, and semantic markup is important. Put that mapping inside a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), not a `<div>` at the very least.

Comment: @FelixKling it is complaining... "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: Probably because your data initially doesn't have a `students` property. Maybe you want `setUserData(data.students);` and `userData.map(...)` instead.

Comment: @FelixKling you are right, it is displaying. However, I have array of array within the properties, do I need to run .map() on it to display its properties

Comment: Depends on how exactly you want to display it. Calling `.map` again is definitely the most flexible way.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate, { student.grades.map() } right?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following changes:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({ students: [] });

...

return (
    <div>
      {userData.students.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>{item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you. Please, how do I use accordion in react